# Keras: How to implement reordering for o/p of a layer in keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have nine, 500 dimensional vectors as o/p from a combination of merge layer followed a reshape layer:

```
...
N=3
merge_rf=merge(cells_rf,mode='concat')
rf_top = Reshape((N*N, 500))(merge_rf)
#proper reordering code here - TODO
```

...

```
>>> rf_top.shape 
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(9), Dimension(500)])
```

I need to reorder these `(9, 500)` dim vectors in `rf_top` using a known mapping

```
eg - (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) to -> (0,1,2,5,4,3,6,7,8) for rf_top
```

Which keras layer should I use for this? and How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
reorder_top = merge([Lambda(lambda x: x[:, index, :], 
    output_shape = (1, 500))(rf_top) for index in permutation], 
    mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
```

Where `permutation` is the permutation according to which you want to permute your layer. The output of this layer is flattened so you should `reshape` it by:

```
reorder_top = Reshape ((N*N, 500))(reorder_top)
```